# Поиск слов-анаграмм в массиве

Tags: ruby

Изучаю Ruby, появилась интересная задачка, но не знаю как реализовать.
Требуется написать функцию, на входе задается массив слов. Требуется вывести группы слов-анаграмм. 
Как я представляю решение: Сделать массив "слов в виде массива букв" с помощью split и сравнивать массивы на их состав

Comment: Как я понял, тебе подойдет [такое](https://github.com/SergeyPotrubach/Ruby/blob/master/anagramm.rb) решение.

Comment: спасибо за наводку, попробую оптимизировать это

Comment: `.group_by { |word| word.chars.to_set }.values`? ([group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by))

Comment: Генератор кросвордов или что?

Comment: D-side, спасибо за ответ. немножко поправил и заработало
array.group_by{|word| word.chars.sort.to_a }.values